# Are there merge tags to reference "Groups" fields?

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to use merge tags for "Groups" fields. List fields and conditional merge tags work fine. Here what I want:

I have List "A" and within a Group "Hobbies" with Values like "Sport", "Cars" etc.
Automated "Cars" workflow get triggered once a user subscribes to "Cars" for example. Now I want to read out and show all hobbies the user has selected in his profile in the content of an email like "Here the hobbies you selected when registering". One way to do it is with INTEREST clause, but that is way too cumbersome.

Hence is there something like *|Groups:Hobbies|* which would yield the result? Or is there a more elegant way to do that than using INTEREST merge tags?